# Why the Median-Three-Partition in QuickSort will hide the pivot before returning the pivot value?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, median

I was confused by this median3 function in quick sort (it comes from Mark Allen Weiss's *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C*):

```
ElementType
Median3(ElementType A[], int Left, int Right){
    int Center = (Left + Right)/2;

    if(A[Left] > A[Center]{
        Swap(&A[Left], &A[Center]);
    }
    if(A[Left] > A[Right]{
        Swap(&A[Left], &A[Right]);
    }
    if(A[Center] > A[Right]{
        Swap(&A[Center], &A[Right]);
    }

    Swap( &A[Center], &A[Right - 1]);  /* Hide pivot */
    return A[right - 1];
}
```

Why does this function hide the pivot before it return the pivot value?

My thinking is that it want to reduce the impact of the pivot in recursive quick sort. Because each time Quick Sort do a recursive calls to itself with left/right part, the center element will be the edge.

Is that right? Hope someone could help me. Thx~!

Comment: Did you see the explanation in Section 7.7.2? It's to prevent worst-case behavior.

Comment: Yeah ~! I got it. Thx for your help~! : )